# Need some help on using LibraryLink

Tags: librarylink

I'm learning to set up a LibraryLink in Mathematica.
I'm able to reproduce some [basic examples](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/189735/) provided in Wolfram community.
But I got stuck while doing a new one by myself.

My source C file is given as follows.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  dd_ErrorType err;
  dd_set_global_constants();
  dd_log=dd_TRUE;
  dd_DDFile2File(argv[1],argv[2],&err);
  return 0;}
```

In the source file, `argv[1]` is the input, which is supposed to be a *txt* file; and `argv[2]` is the output, which is also a *txt* file.

How should I wrap the C source file to create a library (.dll)?

Comment: If you are trying to pass files as pointers between your code and mathematica then its not wrong to say that Library link does not support passing file pointers from WolframLanguage to Mathematica and vice versa. You can check the supported types of MArgument union present in WolframLibrary.h(Contents/SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/C)